# List from Class with Generic Type from different Class but same Interface in C#

Tags: c#

As said in the title, I want to create list of class with generic type. My Class look like this:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
    where T : ISomeClass
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public List<T> ListClass { get; set; }
}

public interface ISomeClass
{
    public string PropInterface { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : ISomeClass
{
    public string PropClassA { get; set; }
    public string PropInterface { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : ISomeClass
{
    public string PropClassB { get; set; }
    public string PropInterface { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to create List of the Generic Type Class with data from `ClassA` and `ClassB`

I tried to do like this, but it error:

```
var list = new List<GenericClass<ISomeClass>>();
list.Add(new GenericClass<ClassA> 
{
    PropA = "Prop Generic", 
    ListClass = new List<ClassA> 
    { 
        new ClassA { PropClassA = "Property A", PropInterface = "..." }
    } 
}); // error cannot convert from 'GenericClass<ClassA>' to 'GenericClass<ISomeClass>'
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

apparently I should do like this:

```
var list = new List<GenericClass<ISomeClass>>();
list.Add(new GenericClass<ISomeClass> 
{
    PropA = "Prop Generic", 
    ListClass = new List<ISomeClass> 
    { 
        new ClassA { PropClassA = "Property A", PropInterface = "..." }
    } 
});
```

but I got other case, where I already have the list of `ClassA` and try to use it to `ListClass` it got error, here's the example:

```
var listA = new List<ClassA> { new ClassA { ... } };

var list = new List<GenericClass<ISomeClass>>();
list.Add(new GenericClass<ISomeClass> { ListClass = listA }); // error cannot implicity convert type 'ClassA' to 'ISomeClass'
```

Comment: either you are not getting the error you are sharing or you are not sharing the correct code.

Comment: @Chetan ups sorry, I share the wrong code in the example. I already edited, thanks for letting me know

Comment: You probably mean `list.Add(new GenericClass<ISomeClass> { //[...] ListClass = new List<ISomeClass>() { new ClassA { ... }, new ClassB { ... }}`

Comment: Tried this `list.Add(new GenericClass<ISomeClass> { ListClass = new List<ISomeClass>() { new ClassA (), new ClassB ()}});`

Comment: ah yes, it work like this. but if I already have the list for `ClassA`, and I want to use it to `ListClass`, do I need to cast it to `ISomeClass` ?

Comment: Like this example, `var listA = new List<ClassA> { new ClassA { ... } };` and I try to put `listA` to `ListClass` like this: `list.Add(new GenericClass<ISomeClass> { ListClass = listA });` it got error `error cannot implicity convert type 'ClassA' to 'ISomeClass'`

Comment: I already edit the question to make it easy to read

Comment: `var listA = new List<ISomeClass> { new ClassA { ... } };`